# Using Joins to fetch specific sets of data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, select

I am trying to print a trial balance with data that is received from 3 different MySQL database tables.

The structure is as follows:

[PostGL] : AccountLink, Debit and Credit

[GLAccountTypes] : AccountType , Description

[Accounts] : AccountLink , AccountType , Account Number

I am trying to use the following SELECT query to fetch the data as such:

Views.py:

```
def Kyletrb(request):
    trialBalance =  'SELECT  [dbo].[PostGL].[Debit] , [dbo].[PostGL].[Credit], [dbo].[Accounts].[Master_Sub_Account] ,[dbo].[_etblGLAccountTypes].[cAccountTypeDescription] FROM [Kyle] INNER JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[_etblGLAccountTypes] ON [Kyle].[dbo].[PostGL].[AccountLink] = SELECT [Kyle].[dbo].[Accounts].[AccountLink] INNER JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[PostGL] ON [Kyle].[dbo].[Accounts].[iAccountType] =   [dbo].[_etblGLAccountTypes].[idGLAccountType] '

    cursor.execute(trialBalance);
    trialBalanceFinal = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]

    return render(request , 'main/Kyletrb.html' , {'trialBalance' : trialBalanceFinal} )
```

Error Message:

> NameError at /Kyletrb
> name 'cursor' is not defined
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/Kyletrb
> Django Version:   3.2
> Exception Type:   NameError
> Exception Value:
> name 'cursor' is not defined
> Exception Location:   C:\Users\KylePOG\Documents\GMA Programming\accConnect\main\views.py, line 26, in Kyletrb
> Python Executable:    C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.9.4
> Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\KylePOG\Documents\GMA Programming\accConnect',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
> 'C:\Users\KylePOG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:  Tue, 31 Aug 2021 11:00:05 +0000

What I expect the output to be :
[image]

Is there anyway to use the **JOIN** function in the SQL query to fetch the Account Number , Description , Credit & Debit where the accountLink and accountTypes Match

Comment: Yes, a JOIN is the standard way.

Comment: When asking SQL questions. you should provide sample table data _and the expected result_, all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve] - make it easy assist you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join all three tables like so:

```
SELECT t1.AccountNumber, t2.Description, t3.Credit, t3.Debit
FROM Accounts t1 
   INNER JOIN GLAccountTypes t2
      ON t1.AccountType = t2.AccountType
   INNER JOIN PostGL t3
      ON t1.AccountLink = t3.AccountLink
```

Comment: I have edited the code with the SQL Query now, this is what it essentially has to do. (Not sure if I've gotten the format correct )

Comment: I have tested it. As per the question, it is now showing an error message with the execute function. I had added the SQL Query on one line (thinking this was the problem) but it's still not executing.

Comment: @KyleStranger What exactly is the error message?

Comment: NameError Exception Value:
name 'cursor' is not defined Exception Location

Comment: So its not an error in the statement. Seems like you did not defined cursor or defined it wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236604/discussion-between-m--i-k-and-kylestranger).

Comment: I have sent a message on this discussion regarding the error